# Integral of $ \cos (x^3)$

Tags: calculus

Is there a way to evaluate $\int \cos(x^3)dx$? I do not mean $\cos^3(x)$

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Please share with us whatever you have tried to address the problem.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use taylor series of $\cos x$
$$\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+....$$
so
$$\cos x^3=1-\frac{x^6}{2!}+\frac{x^{12}}{4!}-\frac{x^{18}}{6!}+....$$
$$\int \cos x^3dx=x-\frac{x^7}{(7)(2!)}+\frac{x^{13}}{(13)(4!)}-\frac{x^{19}}{(19)(6!)}+....+C$$